# Getting a directory listing instead of login menu in localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I am unable to reach `phpmyadmin` login menu in order to login.

Typing `localhost/phpmyadmin` gets me a listing of directory, but no login menu for `phpmyadmin`.

Why do i get a directory listing and not login menu?

I have checked the follwoing:

- PHP running
- MySQL running
- apache2.4 running
- tried different conf of extension=mysqli in php file

Nothing seems to work, can anyone help?

Comment: can you specify if you are using something like "MAMP" or if you're using php on a tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

The main suspicion in this case would be PHP not being installed. You have to make sure that it is running correctly, just try to run a php file inside your apache server, and if it outputs as wished then it is good to go.

You have to make sure that the DirectoryIndex directive is configurated correctly in the configuration of apache.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

That is an example of a DirectoryIndex directive, yours probably does not have the index.php in it, so just add it, and try to restart the server and access again.

If it is still not working make sure that the PHP mods are working along with your server.